# SIGPOLL (SIGIO) problem: interrupt while executing a handler

Tags: c, handler, signals

I am implementing a client and server that communicate over UDP using sendto() and recvfrom(). I wanted to use SIGPOLL for my client when receiving data from the server. My issue is that while in the handler, another signal arrives and it gets lost. I've read there is a kernel variable (a flag) that gets set that I could check before exiting the handler, but I can't seem to find out which flag that is.

```
void my_receive_server_data(int sig_num)
{
    /* execute recvfrom() */
}
```

And in main:

```
    setup_action.sa_handler = my_receive_server_data;
    if (sigaction(SIGPOLL, &setup_action, NULL) == -1)
            perror("Sigaction");

    if (fcntl(sock, F_SETOWN, getpid()) < 0) {
            perror("fcntl");
    }
    if (fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, O_RDONLY | FASYNC) < 0) {
            perror("fcntl");
    }
```

Currently, if I do not put a sleep() after sendto() in the server, only the first sendto() gets executed by the client (in the handler, as a recvfrom()). Putting sleep() fixes the problem, so I highly believe it is because the handler only gets run once (because it is getting the data while still executing my_receive_server_data).

I would like to please know what flag I should check before returning from my_receive_server_data to check if any input has arrived while that handler was executing please.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why do you want to use `SIGPOLL`? I think it's generally accepted that this is a really bad design, especially since most functions **cannot** be called from signal handlers, and that `SIGPOLL` and the interfaces to use it only remain in POSIX due to legacy applications that need them. You should learn to use `select` or `poll` and write a proper network application.

Comment: @R.. Do you have any resources you can share about why most functions cannot be called from signal handlers?

Comment: @Matthew: For POSIX, see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03_03. For plain C it's even more restrictive; I can lookup the citation if you need it.

Answer (score 2):

It's very hard to create a solid system the way you're trying to. Instead of signals, learn to use blocking call models, and I/O multiplexing with `select()` or `poll()`.

If you intend to use signals no matter what, try to reduce the code in the signal handler to a minimum -- maybe just sending a byte down a pipe to wake up a sleeping thread or process, or whatever.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand your explanation and it looks good, but unfortunately, I have to use SIGPOLL (the choice isn't mine). I still do need to know the flag.

Answer (score 2):

The flag is `SA_NODEFER` passed to sigaction when defining a handler for `SIGPOLL`.